# FFTW3 On Raspberry Pi - fftw3.h no such file or directory compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, fftw

Followed the instructions for installing fftw3, running on my Raspberry Pi.

Ran the following commands.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

When I try to compile my program, I get the error fftw3.h no such file or directory.

Where on my system should the include files be, and where has the fftw3 install process put them? I assume they are in the wrong place? How can I correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to run with admin privileges:

`sudo make install` will put the libraries in `/usr/local/lib`